# UITableview cell row height issue in ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(!isPopover)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
        {
            return 122;
        }
        else
            return 60;
    }
    else
    {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

same method i used in IoS7. Working fine over there.Help me on this

Comment: What is your question? What result does this code give you?

Comment: When the view appears, row height of my tableview should be 60 and then later if i perform some action row height should change to 122....Same cell i'm just increasing and decreasing the row height. This is the actual scenarion...This code does not work in ios8 but works perfect in ios7

Answer (score 0):

IOS8 sets the tableViewCell row height, depending on whats in the subView of ContentView. If you have a label in the subView and you want to restrict the lines in the label text then use the `noOfLines` property to restrict the lines and hence the height of the tableViewCell, similarly if you have buttons or images in the tableView you could size them appropriately, such that tableViewCell will size its height accordingly.